# Use && operator with filter() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a mental block that does not allow me to move forward.

I have an array that I will exemplify with the following code:

```
let cars = [
  { brand: "Ford", year: "2012", color: "White", doors: "5", model: "One" },
  { brand: "Chevrolet", year: "2021", color: "Red", doors: "5", model: "Two" },
  { brand: "Chevrolet", year: "2000", color: "Black", doors: "5", model: "Three" },
  { brand: "Citroen", year: "2004", color: "Pink", doors: "3", model: "Four" },
];
```

I need to store in a variable all those cars that meet the condition of having 5 doors. Well,

```
let carsWithFiveDoors = cars.filter(({ doors }) => doors == "5");
```

But I also need it to meet two conditions at the same time. To be more clear, to my new array that has only those 5-door cars, I need to apply another filter that allows me to have only those cars that are not Chevrolet branded, nor red. The problem arises when, by simple logic, I apply this method to my array:

```
carsWithFiveDoors.filter(({ brand, color }) => brand !== "Chevrolet" && color !== "Red");
```

The result of this filter is the following array:

```
let newArrayOfCars = [
  {
    brand: "Ford",
    year: "2012",
    color: "White",
    doors: "5",
    model: "One",
  },
  {
    brand: "Toyota",
    year: "2000",
    color: "Black",
    doors: "5",
    model: "Three",
  },
  {
    brand: "Citroen",
    year: "2004",
    color: "Pink",
    doors: "3",
    model: "Four",
  },
];
```

With that method what I achieved was to generate **an array without any Chevrolet vehicles, but I need to filter out those cars that, at the same time, are red and Chevrolet branded**.

How could I achieve this? I've given it a lot of thought and I think I've already burned out.

Comment: Why would Citreon be in that array? It has three doors. You also have no Toyotas in that original list so why is it appearing in the final output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to filter out cars that are both brand `Chevrolet` and red, you need to implement the following logical expression:

```js
let newArrayOfCars = carsWithFiveDoors.filter(({ brand, color }) => !(brand === "Chevrolet" && color === "Red"));
```

Comment: i downvoted this because all you are doing is switching this statement to be `brand === 'Chevrolet' && color === 'Red'` - which is the polar opposite of what he wants.

Comment: @JonathonHibbard that was my typo. I meant `!(brand === "Chevrolet" && color === "Red")`. Thanks for your comment

Comment: roger - i changed the downvote to an upvote

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a double filter here in this case. Use the below code and this should solve your ask.

```
let newArrayOfCars = cars.filter(({ doors }) => doors == "5").filter(({ brand, color }) => brand !== "Chevrolet" && color !== "Red");
```

Also note that you can try putting all the three conditions at once in a single filter using &&.

Comment: If you aren't going to store the return of the first filter then it is more efficient to combine them into one

Answer (score 1):

`filter` will always return a new array - you can't filter on an array in place. So you will need a new filter on the `carsWithFiveDoors` array to produce a new array of `noRedFiveDoorChevs`.

Note: the actual output will not result in your expected output.

```js
const cars = [
  { brand: "Ford", year: "2012", color: "White", doors: "5", model: "One" },
  { brand: "Chevrolet", year: "2021", color: "Red", doors: "5", model: "Two" },
  { brand: "Chevrolet", year: "2000", color: "Black", doors: "5", model: "Three" },
  { brand: "Citroen", year: "2004", color: "Pink", doors: "3", model: "Four" },
];

const carsWithFiveDoors = cars.filter(({ doors }) => doors === "5");

const noRedFiveDoorChevs = carsWithFiveDoors.filter(({ brand, color }) => {
  return brand !== "Chevrolet" && color !== "Red"
});

console.log(noRedFiveDoorChevs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, you need to use `===` instead of `==` - which is why you see 3 door cars in your search results along with 5.

```js
let carsWithFiveDoors = cars.filter(({ doors }) => doors === "5");
```

Also, I think you can simplify this by replacing `&&` with `||` which will filter out any cars that are red or chevrolete (which is what I think you're saying you want).  Feel free to correct me and i'll update the answer.

I think what you want though is this:

```js
let carsWithFiveDoors = cars.filter({ doors, brand, color } => (doors === "5" && (brand !== "Chevrolet" || color !== 'Red'))
```

Comment: 1) Using `==` wouldn't just make a car with three doors appear in the output. 2) Because then the name `carsWithFiveDoors` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Yes it would.  Which is why you can see the 3 door car in the output @Andy.  Look at his original post and you'll see `{ brand: "Citroen", year: "2004", color: "Pink", doors: "3", model: "Four" }`.  This is because in Javascript, `"3" == "5"` will return `true`, whereas `"3" === "5"` would result in `false`.  His original statement is he wanted to ONLY show cars with 5 doors.  he then wanted to filter out any red cards but also chevrolete cars. so the statement `doors == "5"` will match _both_ `3` _and_ `5`

Comment: @JonathonHibbard that isn't right, `"3" == "5"` returns `false`, not `true`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the Citroen (with three doors) in the expected output isn't in the original data so I don't know where that's coming from. @JonathonHibbard

Comment: @NickParsons yea i'm dyslexic tonight lol  yea i understand @Andy - was just explaining the reasoning behind doing the `===` vs `==`